# Как передать 1 переменную из одного модуля в другой

Tags: vba

Всем доброго времени суток,нужно написать программу для курсовой,начал изучать VBA,столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть массив

> Dim one(2) As Variant

Нужно первый аргумент из этого массива передать в другой модель,функцию...точно не знаю как называется.
То есть из функции test() нужно передать массив one() в функцию transport().
Заранее благодарю за ответы
Сам код:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
Dim one(2) As Variant
     one(1) = InputBox("Введите название для первого сорта зерна")
     one(2) = InputBox("Введите цену для первого сорта зерна")
Cells(2, 1) = UCase(one(1))
Cells(2, 2) = one(2)
End Sub

Sub transport()
Dim oneWeek(7) As Long
Dim twoWeek(7) As Long
Dim threeWeek(7) As Long
Dim fourWeek(7) As Long
Dim fiveWeek(7) As Long

Dim switch As Variant
     switch = InputBox("Введите название сорта для добавления количества отгрузки")



End Sub
```

Comment: Определите их на уровне модуля, а не процедуры, например...

Comment: а подробнее можно,пожалуйста,только первый день использую VBA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Dim MyArray(1 to 2)

Public Sub sub1()
' инициализация значений '
MyArray(1) = "2*2 = "
MyArray(2) = 2*2
End Sub

Public sub2()
' использование значений '
MsgBox MyArray(1) & MyArray(2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

По Вашему коду не видно, в какой момент нужно передавать управление другой функции.

```
Public Sub test()
........
Call transport(one)
End Sub

Sub transport(a())
.......
```

Comment: если есть возможность,уделите минуту моему коду(http://imgur.com/a/WnI98) первая функция вызывается при клики на кнопку в экселе,нужно чтобы при клике на вторую кнопку можно было работать с массивом one